# How to insert Time in a range of excel sheet which should not update automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Friends I want to insert time in a range which should not get updated automatically. For example if there is any value in cell no k5 then the current time should automatically be inserted in cell no N5. Similarly if there is any value in k6 then the current time should be automatically be inserted in N6, so on.. Moreover it should not be updated automatically. I tried to use this formula

> =IF(K5<0,"",IF(K5=0,"",NOW()))

This formula is working but it is auto updating the time with the system's clock. I want it should not update the time. You can see the snapshot also-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Lqr.png
PLEASE HELP ME...THANKS A LOT...

Answer (score 0):

First enter your column **K** data and then run this short macro:

```
Sub RecordTime()
   Dim rng As Range, r As Range, d As Date
   Set rng = Intersect(Range(Cells(5, "K"), Cells(Rows.Count, "K")), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
   d = TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()))

   For Each r In rng
      If r.Value <> "" Then
         r.Offset(0, 3) = d
      End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is an automatic version of the code.  Insert the following *Event macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rng As Range, r As Range, d As Date
   Set rng = Intersect(Range(Cells(5, "K"), Cells(Rows.Count, "K")), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

   If Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then Exit Sub

   d = TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()))
   Application.EnableEvents = False
      Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = d
   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

If you change a cell in column **K** the time will automatically be recorded in column **L**.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Dear @Gary's Student thanks for your kind reply, sir, the codes suggested by you are not working. when I put any value in k5 and then k6 and so on.. it does not show time in N5 and N6 and so on.. please help me sir...

Comment: Dear @Gary's Student, the codes suggested by you are inserting time at once in the column N. I want that when I enter any data in cell no k5 then it should automatically insert the current time which is remain fix i.e. should not change with system's clock in N5. Moreover there is formula in entire column K so I will enter some data in row A to J and calculated value will automatically be inserted in column K. Please help..

Comment: @ramji See my **EDIT#1**